# Referencing an object in an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var Bar = function(){

}

Bar.prototype.drawBar = function(obj){ 

}

var bars = [];// Creating array 
for (i = 0;i < ar.length ;i++){
    bars[i] = [new Bar(ar[i],i)]; // Creating array of objects
    bars[i].drawBar(i);// I am looking for something like this, Currently it doesn't work
}
```

I have something like this, How do I draw a bar, giving a reference/index, It should draw with the measurements

Comment: What bar? Do you mean a graph?

Comment: You probably want `bars[i] = new Bar(ar[i],i);`. Or do you really want an array of arrays?

Comment: I juat want this. @felix

Comment: you are right @Jan Its a kind of simple graph.

Comment: So you are asking how to draw a graph with JavaScript, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `bars[i]` as if it was a `Bar` object, but it's an array of objects.

Use this to access the first object in the array:

```
bars[i][0].drawBar(i);
```

If you don't have any use for an array of arrays, just store the objects in the array directly:

```
bars[i] = new Bar(ar[i],i);
```

Then your original code to access the object works.